# How can my client edit the website I have built for them using webpack once the site is live?

Tags: javascript, webpack, module, client, edit

I am in the process of building a website for a local company, the site is built using webpack, no frameworks, just vanilla js with import/export, css and html, is there a way, once the website is complete that the client can edit the site without relying on me or learning to code?

I have asked this question all over google and youtube and I cannot find an answer anywhere. I did find some vague answers for normal sites but nothing for sites built using webpack.

Comment: The answer is no, they'll have to deal with whatever code you wrote for them.

Comment: ok, because I did read something about a cms, it was related to a blog which had a system in place for clients to update text/images etc, i just couldnt find any information on where to find it or how to use it, so this means everytime they want to add new products to the site or new text they will have to get me to do it for them??@Pointy